# $f \in C[a,b]$ , $f''$ exists in $(a,b)$ ; $\exists t \in (0,1) : f(ta+(1-t)b)=tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$ ; then $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that $f''(c)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function , twice differentiable in $(a,b)$ ,

such that $\exists t \in (0,1)$ such that $f(ta+(1-t)b)=tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$ ; then is it true that $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that $f''(c)=0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derivative satisfies [intermediate value property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) even if it might be discontinuous. That means if $f''(c)\neq 0$ on $(a,b)$, either $f''(c)>0$ on $(a,b)$ or $f''(c)<0$ on $(a,b)$. In both cases $f(ta+(1-t)b)=tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$ cannot be true by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function).